# I cannot validate an email received in parameters in postman

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am checking validation of email by sending a parameter (email) in API. I defined validations in the user model.

User controller:

```
if User.validates?(:email => params[:email])
  render json: {message: "email"}, status: :ok
else
  render json: {message: "phone"}, status: :bad
end
```

User model:

```
validates_presence_of :name, :email, :contact, :password_digest
validates :email, uniqueness: true
#encrypt password
has_secure_password
```

It gives an error in postman:

```
 "exception": "#<NoMethodError: undefined method `validates?' for #<Class:0x00007fbcdc0b0770>\nDid you mean?  validates\n               validate\n               validates!\n               validators\n               _validators?>",
"traces": {
    "Application Trace": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "trace": "app/controllers/v1/users_controller.rb:34:in `login'"
        }
    ]
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Actually, I want to make login user through email and contact both, So I was thinking  to check if a parameter is an email then it should check its validation then execute rest of code, otherwise go in else condition

Comment: You can't validate just a plain string parameter. Validation is for model instances. You can build a user with received params and check if it is `valid?`

Comment: I tried what you said but giving this error :
<ArgumentError: Unknown key: :uniqueness. Valid keys are: :on, :if, :unless, :prepend. Perhaps you meant to call `validates` instead of `validate`

Comment: Could you please update the question and add code of attempt and error?

Answer (score 3):

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def foo
    if valid_email?(params[:email])
      render json: {message: "email"}, status: :ok
    else
      render json: {message: "phone"}, status: :bad
    end
  end

  private

  def valid_email?(email)
    VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
    email.present? &&
    (email =~ VALID_EMAIL_REGEX) &&
    User.find_by(email: email).empty?
  end
end
```

You can do something like this.
However, I would say that validation still belongs in the model, even if it isn't an ActiveRecord-based one. Please take a look at how to use ActiveModel::Validations:

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Validations.html http://yehudakatz.com/2010/01/10/activemodel-make-any-ruby-object-feel-like-activerecord/ http://asciicasts.com/episodes/219-active-model

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

It's throwing you a no method error for the method `validates?` which doesn't exist.
Maybe you want to use the method `valid?` However, you can only call `valid?` on an instance not on the class User. You might want to change the code a bit more.

https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#valid-questionmark-and-invalid-questionmark

Comment: `valid?` is an instance method, but he tries to do something with User class